# Delete text before period

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do the following.

I have a column with names like:

```
A. Baker
B.J. Street
etc.
```

I want to copy this entire row into a new column and then delete the initials. So basically I have to delete everything until the last `.` and an extra space behind the `.`.

Comment: Do some research.  There are numerous examples on this forum

Comment: look for a combination of the functions `Right()` and `Find()`, possibly combined with the `Len()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your string is in A2 then try this...

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),LEN(A2)))
```

So if A2 has `B.J. Street` in it, the formula will return `Street`.

Comment: The OP didn't specify anywhere that he is interested in a VBA solution, though the VBA tag was added. I suggested formula because this is the easiest way for him to place this formula in another column and drag it down. I din't post the VBA solution as the next question would be how to implement it. Didn't take much interest as OP didn't share what he has tried so far, so just gave him a starting point.